# Dynamic Expression Methods

Tags: linq, dynamic

I have the following code:

```
return Expression.Call(
    typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable),
    "Like",
    new Type[] { typeof(string) },
    Expression.Constant(filter.Value),
    Expression.Coalesce(member, Expression.Constant(string.Empty))
);
```

Alright, so instead of using "Contains", I'd like to create my own extension method called "Like", and then do something specific. I went off and created an extension method like normal:

```
public static bool Like<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value)
{
    return true;
}
```

I'm returning true for now to try to get things to work. The error I get is that "Like" is not a method of Enumerable. I can use that new extension method on it's own but not from within the expression.call.

Any ideas what might be the issue? I mean, the "Contains" is fine if I want exact text searches but I really want what the method implies, "LIKE" searches.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code is calling the static `Enumerable.Contains<T>(Ienumerable<T>,T)` - it is not triggered as an extension method, but as a regular static method call.

For example, if you have:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Like<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You should write:

```
Expression.Call(
    typeof(StringExtensions),   // the class that contains the extension method
    "Like",
    new Type[] { typeof(string) },
    Expression.Constant(array), // this is the IEnumerable<string>
    Expression.Constant(String.Empty)
);
```

Comment: I edited my post and its actually calling the "Like" method. NOt sure why its saying "Like" is not a method of Enumerable. Thanks

Comment: @DavidWhitten - I've edited the question to explain what I meant, let me know if that's the right direction.

Comment: Holy crap, thanks much for pointing out to use the actual extension class type. That's the only thing I had to change. I'm in business.